# Open Graph post not shown facebook mobile news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, feed

I'm able to see the open graph post in facebook **web newsfeed** but not able to see same post in **mobile** facebook newsfeed? What can be the reason ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After some research i concluded the below things:

Facebook don't allow "Open Graph" on mobile site or on the mobile app. Just to reduce the traffic. It seems that some algorithms are working which prevent this post for the mobile sites.

So if "Open Graph" story/post would only be visible on Facebook web site and that is in the current activity log first and after some time on User's Facebook wall post.